# regex for all UK telephone numbers

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to validate UK telephone numbers, which are in the format of:

```
01234 567890

01234567890

02012345678

020 1234 5678
```

I have the following regex, which works for all apart from the `020 1234 5678`

`^\s*\(?(020[7,8]{1}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9{2}[ ]?[0-9]{4})|(0[1-8]{1}[0-9]{3}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[ ]?[0-9]{3})\s*$`

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: I don't know what language you are using, but it would be useful to use some `strip_spaces` function. So you simply don't bother with the spacing between numbers.

Comment: `$normalized = str_replace(' ', '', $number);` (I don't know, why everyone wants to use regular expression for everything...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing a closing square bracket

```
^\s*\(?(020[7,8]{1}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9{2}[ ]?[0-9]{4})|(0[1-8]{1}[0-9]{3}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[ ]?[0-9]{3})\s*$
                                      ^
                                     here
```

This should be working

```
^\s*\(?(020[7,8]{1}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[ ]?[0-9]{4})|(0[1-8]{1}[0-9]{3}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[ ]?[0-9]{3})\s*$
```

Further you can remove some stuff from your expression.

`{1}` is not need every character is still matched once

`[ ]` is also not needed, just replace it with a space

`[8,9]` is wrong. it will match 8, 9 and , . Use `[89]` is correct.

Then it would look like that

```
^\s*\(?(020[78]\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2} ?[0-9]{4})|(0[1-8][0-9]{3}\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2} ?[0-9]{3})\s*$
```

If you want to allow this not matched pattern **020 1234 5678** you could do for example

```
^\s*\(?(020[78]?\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2,3} ?[0-9]{4})$|^(0[1-8][0-9]{3}\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2} ?[0-9]{3})\s*$
               ^                 ^^
made the [78] optional        allows no 2 or 3 of `[0-9]`
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u57f)

I have no clue if this is a valid UK phone number!

I fixed here also another bug in the regex a missing `$` before and a missing `^` after the pipe `|`

Comment: Adding that square bracket did not fix the validation on the particular number format

Comment: @ terrid25, yes because your pattern doesn't allow it. 020 has to be followed by a 7 or a 8 and in the second group there are only 3 digits allowed.

Comment: @terrid25 maybe you want to use a regex tester: your Problem on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u579)

Comment: @ stema, that still doesn't seem to solve the problem. `020 1234 5678` is still not recognized as a valid number using the above regex.

Comment: @terrid25, see my first comment on this answer. Your pattern does not allow it. You need to define what is a valid pattern for a phone number, then we can adjust.

Comment: @terrid25, I added a changed pattern to my solution, try it, but I don't know if a phone number of this format is valid.

Comment: Examples of valid numbers are:  02081234567, 0208 123 4567, 01234 567890, 01234 567 890, 01234567890, 020 7123 4567.

Comment: @terrid25, your examples are all matched by my changed version [Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u581). But I can not promise that it will not match a wrong one.

Comment: Thanks for you help on this. I noticed that the following block: ?[1-9][0-9]{2} caused mobile numbers that had double zero's at a certain position to fail. for example: 07515009999. I updated the expression to allow for these: ^\s*\(?(020[78]?\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2,3} ?[0-9]{4})|(0[1-8][0-9]{3}\)? ?[0-9][0-9]{2} ?[0-9]{3})\s*$

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Perl [Number::Phone::UK](http://search.cpan.org/~dcantrell/Number-Phone-3.4002/lib/Number/Phone/UK.pm) can check if a number is valid, allocated, mobile, personal or business... and so on.

Answer (score -1):

`020` Does not follow with a 7 or 8.

The London phone code was unified into one single area code. `020`. The remaining numbers are the landline, as such the format 020 7123 4567 is correct. See [ofcom](http://www.ofcom.org.uk/) website.

Answer (score -1):

My JS solution

```
var total = 0;
var passed = 0;
var failed = 0;

var r = /^(?:(?:\(?(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?(?:\(?0\)?[\s-]?)?)|(?:\(?0))(?:(?:\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5})|(?:\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3}))|(?:\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4})|(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}))(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?|\#)\d{3,4})?$/;

var pass = [
    '(0123) 456 7890',
    '012 3456 7890',
    '+44 12345 67890',
    '+44 1234567890',
    '0044 1234 567 890',
    '0044 1234 567890',
];

pass.each ( function (value) {
    var result = r.test( value );
    console.log( value, (result == true ? 'ok' : 'failed') );

    total ++;
    if ( result == true ) {
        passed ++;
    } else {
        failed ++;
    }

} );


var fail = [
    '(0123) 456 78',
    '012 3456 789',
    '+44 12345 678',
    '0044 1234 567 89',
];

fail.each ( function (value) {
    var result = r.test( value );
    console.log( value,  (result == false ? 'ok' : 'failed') );

    total ++;
    if ( result == false ) {
        passed ++;
    } else {
        failed ++;
    }
} );

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log( "PASSED " + passed + ' / ' + total );
}, 500);
```