# Regular expression for UK Mobile Number - Python

Tags: python, regex, django

I need a regular expression that only validates **UK mobile numbers**.

A UK mobile number can be between `10-14` digits and either starts with `07`, or omits the `0` and starts with `447`.

Importantly, if the user adds `+44` it should be rejected.

So these would be valid:

> 07111111111
>
> 447111111111

and these would be invalid:

> +4471111111111
>
> 021929182711
>
> 00701029182

---

What I have so far:

```
rule = re.compile(r'^\+?(44)?(0|7)\d{9,13}$')

if not rule.search(value):
    msg = u"Invalid mobile number."
    raise ValidationError(msg)
```

This does not validate according to my rules yet; could someone help?

Comment: This StackOverflow post might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582309/regex-for-all-uk-telephone-numbers

Comment: @user2246087 It looks like this is a subset of UK numbers that he/she wants validated.  This isn't an exact duplicate in that sense.

Comment: @BlackVegetable I did not mean it is a duplicate, Mentioned it for reference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following regex seems like it would fit your requirements, if I understand them correctly.

Not allowing a + sign is very easy as you're only creating a whitelist of values, and the plus isn't among them.

`^(07[\d]{8,12}|447[\d]{7,11})$`

As was mentioned in the comments for this answer, the square brackets are not necessary here.  I included them to make my own reading of this regex a little easier on my eyes.  However, the following works just as well:

`^(07\d{8,12}|447\d{7,11})$`

Comment: Are the square brackets around the `\d` really necessary? I don't mean to nit-pick, but I'm curious whether I'm missing something.

Comment: No, they aren't.  Because regex are so terse to begin with, I find it helps readability to include things like square brackets to make it simple for me to find a bug in my logic, rather than save on 4 characters in the length of a line of regex. @JamesHolderness, great question though.

Comment: Note your Regexp cannot be right, one time you have the prefix + 8-12 numbers, the other time you have the prefix + 7-11 numbers. It should be 8-12 in both cases.

Comment: @mrbrdo I was under the impression that the *total* number of numbers was 10-14.  The prefix in one case is two digits, and the prefix in the other is 3.  Thus the total would be 2+(8~12) and 3+(7~11) both of which equal 10-14.

Comment: Well I'm not from UK, but I am from EU, and for me, my number is e.g. 01 1234567, where 01 is the area code. So my number is 7 numbers and area code is 01. If I use the international prefix - +386 1 - my number is still 1234567, it doesn't magically get shorter because I've changed the prefix. So it's +386 1 1234567. It doesn't become one number shorter like your regexp seems to imply. Unless UK has a totally wicked phone system I would assume it's the same for them.

Comment: @mrbrdo Actually, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_United_Kingdom#New_pager_numbers_start_using_076 .  It actually indicates that the "subscriber number" *can* vary in length depending on several factors!

Comment: But not depending on how you write the prefix. It's still the same number. I'm not trying to discredit your answer, I just want you to fix the regexp since now it can't be right (for the edge cases only, of course). The only problem is I do not know if either 8-12 digits or 7-11 digits must follow 07.
The 07 can be substituted with 447 or +447 freely, but the digits after this prefix are the same. You really don't need to be a telephone genius to know that.

Comment: In other words the correct regexp should be `^(07|447)\d{x,y}$`. The question is if x,y are 7,11 or 8,12. Or even some other number.

Comment: There are UK numbers which start 07 but are not mobile numbers, these start 070. One example is +44 70 0585 0070 [Personal numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_numbering)

Comment: What is the conclusion here - is the answer actually correct?

Comment: @niico I suspect there are exceptions that aren't captured. Unfortunately I don't live in the UK nor am I aware of any resource that would help me build an all-inclusive regex for UK numbers in totality.

Answer (score 1):

I had a play around with @BlackVegetable's answer for a pattern for UK numbers and this works for me `(07\d{9}|447\d{9})$`

Note that this pattern only accounts for UK mobile numbers that are 11 digits in length.