# HTML 5 Regex Pattern for UK Mobile Number

Tags: regex, html, validation

I am trying to validate UK mobile numbers using HTML 5. The following pattern successfully validates but I need the number to begin with +4407 rather than 07.

```
<input type="tel" pattern="^\s*\(?(020[7,8]{1}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9{2}[ ]?[0-9]{4})|(0[1-8]{1}[0-9]{3}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[ ]?[0-9]{3})\s*$" >
```

Comment: I doubt this pattern always validates the numbers successfully (see `[7,8]`).

Comment: Here is a trouble, too`[0-9{2}[ ]?[0-9]{4}`. Looks like the pattern is just a mess. Better re-write  from scratch. Or search on the Web. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405187/regular-expression-for-uk-mobile-number-python). Also, check [this resource](http://www.regxlib.com/UserPatterns.aspx?authorid=d95177b0-6014-4e73-a959-73f1663ae814&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

Comment: Is that the format you are looking for "+4407 xxx xxx xxx"?