# Validating UK phone number (Regex C#)

Tags: c#, regex

```
public static bool ValidatePhoneNumber(string number)
{
    return Regex.Match(number, "^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success;
}
```

This is what I have but I get errors saying `Unrecognized escape sequence`. Can anbody help? needs to be able to have `+44`.

Comment: You need to add `@` in front of the string `@"^(\+44\s?...`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582309/regex-for-all-uk-telephone-numbers

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: @YuliamChandra that got my errors down from 37 to 10

Comment: Take a look at http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx as well as testing it lets you enter the unescaped RegEx and then gives you the C# equivalent string

Comment: Thanks @EaterOfCode - not sure what happened there

Comment: Weird Unicode characters, thats what happend D:

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may try this regex if you are trying to get it with +44

```
^(((\+44\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{4}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|((\+44\s?\d{3}|\(?0\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|((\+44\s?\d{2}|\(?0\d{2}\)?)\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$
```

This will match for

```
+447222555555 | +44 7222 555 555 | (0722) 5555555 #2222
```

**[REGEX DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gV4gP6/1)**

---

You can try this regex for UK phone numbers:

```
/^\(?0( *\d\)?){9,10}$/
```

This regex will check for 10 or 11 digit numbers which are there in UK numbers, starting with a 0, which may have formatting spaces between any of the digits, and optionally a set of brackets for the area code.

Also in your regex you need to add @ to get rid of that error(`Unrecognized escape sequence`):

```
public static bool ValidatePhoneNumber(string number)
{
   return Regex.Match(number, @"^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success;
}
```

Comment: this is not working with `+44`, which was a requirement

Comment: The top one does not work for a ten-digit number 0123456789

Comment: @niico The number 07999999999 passes using the first and last regex's in this answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is a pretty solid regex, will handle area codes, extension numbers and the +44 international code as well as mobile numbers and even 10 digit numbers:

```
^(?:(?:\(?(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?(?:\(?0\)?[\s-]?)?)|(?:\(?0))(?:(?:\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5})|(?:\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3}))|(?:\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4})|(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}))(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?|\#)\d{3,4})?$
```

Comment: This seems a pretty comprehensive regex pattern that matches all valid UK telephone formats listed here:
[area-codes.org.uk](http://www.area-codes.org.uk/formatting.php)
My tests can be found here:
[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/f0HaLr/3)

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
^(\+44\\s?7\\d{3}|\(?07\\d{3}\)?)\\s?\\d{3}\\s?\\d{3}$
```

In order for the regex to recognize the `\s`, `\d`, etc you need to put double slash `\\`. If not you'll get an `illegal escape character` error.

Answer (score 1):

This works well and allows 3 and 4 digit extensions. It also ensures that only mobile numbers are entered. UK mobile numbers start with 07 regardless of the provider

```
^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions; 
    public static bool CheckNumber(string strPhoneNumber)
    {
            string MatchNumberPattern = "^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$";
            if (strPhoneNumber != null)
            {
                return Regex.IsMatch(strPhoneNumber, MatchNumberPattern);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
     }
```

Hope, this code helps you.