# UK Phone Number Regex - no spaces or brackets

Tags: regex, validation

I have only started working with Regex today and need to validate UK telephone numbers.

I don't want any space or brackets to pass validation but I do want the following to be valid:

Numbers starting with:

- 0044
- +44
- 44
- 0

Then the numbers thereafter to be between 9 and 10 digits in length, with the first of these digits being either: 1,2,3,7,8

I have written this:

```
^((^\+44)|^(4{2})|(^0{2}4{2})|(^0)|)[12378]\d{8,9}$
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/jY8aK4/1

It seemed to work but then I realised that 112222222 and 111111111 passed which they shouldn't and I can't think how to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582309/regex-for-all-uk-telephone-numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following regex:

```
^(0044|0|\+?44)[12378]\d{8,9}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yS0hU7/1)

Comment: This did exactly what i needed and is also cleaner. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You regex is almost correct.  The problem is the `|` at the end of your first group.  It allows a null prefix.  See the warning in the explanation at the URL you posted.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Perl, [Number Phone UK](http://search.cpan.org/~dcantrell/Number-Phone-1.8001/lib/Number/Phone/UK.pm) has every convenience method you could possibly need to validate UK phone numbers.